# Geolocation coordinates set for Gnome apps are incorrect

Tags: gnome, 17.04, gnome-shell, geolocation

The coordinates that are set for Gnome apps like Maps, Weather, and Night Light are 500 kilometers away from my current location, causing my desktop to display the wrong location in Maps, display irrelevant weather information, and most annoyingly activate the Night Light about 15 minutes early.

I think the root of the problem is the package "geoclue," and by playing around with the "GeoclueShare" app on my Android phone, I was able to get Maps to display the correct location, but the weather info and Night Shift settings did not change. The only way I could get Night Shift to be on time was to manually change the coordinates in the Dconf Editor, but that always gets reset to the wrong coordinates at startup. I installed the packages "geoclue-manual" and "geoclue-localnet" but they don't seem to be doing anything. Oddly enough, the application "geoclue-test-gui" is displaying reasonably accurate location information, but it's "required accuracy level" drop-down menu is always set to "country." I changed that several times to no avail.

Is there a way to just manually set geo-coordinates in Geoclue? My system is a desktop without any WiFi or GPS hardware and isn't moving around anyway. This [open bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96861) makes it seem like there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your device has wifi and it’s turn on, and there are at least some wifi signals that reach your location, you can actually fix this problem yourself. Install the Mozilla stumbler app on a GPS equipped device, turn it on, and [take a walk](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/contribute-mls-wifi.html) around your house and neighborhood. You may have to do this two–three times and wait a day or two, but location triangulation accuracy should improve for you and your neighborhood in general.

If your device can’t scan for wifi signals and you’re falling back to IP based geolocation, your location will be off by quite a bit. In this case, you can either get a USB wifi dongle or a USB GPS receiver to improve accuracy.

Comment: The OP's system is a desktop.

Comment: **Mozilla Stumbler is DEAD.** You can look at https://location.services.mozilla.com/ to find alternatives. I use the one for Android which Mozilla described as: "**Network Cell Info Lite & WiFi** is an Android application for cell network monitoring, uses MLS and can be configured to optionally contribute data back to MLS." - It was by default configured to share data about geolocaton and nearby WiFi and cell towers. Hopefully this will help Mozilla Location Services figure out my location after my data has been processed! :)